# Mounting a ProxyPass site at the same root url as wordpress

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, uwsgi, mod-proxy

We have a site that is currently running on Wordpress.  We are developing a Django site to replace it.  Overtime, the goal is to slowly replace parts of the Wordpress site with Django.  We would typically set this up for Django something like this:

```
ProxyPass /newcontent/static !
ProxyPass /newcontent uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /newcontent uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/newcontent/ retry=0
```

This will mount the Django/uWSGI app at `ourwebsite.com/newcontent`.  However, this means that all Django URLs will begin at that root, so something like `ourwebsite.com/newcontent/aboutus`.  Is there a way to configure Apache where all requests would go to Wordpress, unless specifically indicated in the conf?  I can imagine that making numerous uWSGI entries would be one way to do it, but then Django is seeing all sorts of base paths, which doesn't work so well internally.

In the end, it would be best if I could do something like:

```
# Normal Wordpress config, DirectoryIndex, etc

# Django Specific Stuff
/about-us                # Goes to Django
/admin/*                 # Django admin
/our-products/*          # This and all subpaths to Django
/static/*                # Same, all static content
```

Additionally, we serve httpS always on Django sites, so It would be preferable to also redirect any Django served URLs to https within Apache.

Over time, we'll just slowly replace wordpress urls until finally, Django is the only thing being served.  At this point, we can just clean up the config to send all URLs to Django.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `ProxyPassMatch`. Here is an untested example:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/newcontent/((one|two|three|four)(/|$).*) uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/$1 retry=0
```

In this, example, `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` are URLs that should be served by Django.

If `ProxyPassMatch` can't do it, it can certainly be done with mod_rewrite.

Regular expressions are hard to understand. Even if you are OK, other people around you will be not. So it's best to avoid them. So an alternative solution, if possible, is to list the Wordpress URLs instead of the Django URLs:

```
ProxyPass /newcontent/five !
ProxyPass /newcontent/six !
ProxyPass /newcontent uwsgi://...
```

where `five` and `six` are to be served by Wordpress.

---

**Update**: I slept over my answer and I wonder; you say

> I can imagine that making numerous uWSGI entries would be one way to do it, but then Django is seeing all sorts of base paths, which doesn't work so well internally.

So what would be the problem with the following?

```
ProxyPass /newcontent/one uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/one
ProxyPass /newcontent/two uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031/two
```